# Hover column in table by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I hover a column with jQuery but one th is over th that will be hovered and when mouse is over that part of th hover doesn't working for column . When width of theadr that over my column is bigger than 80px it work correctly  but i need smallest width

**It is style**

```
      <style>
            .empty { cursor: pointer;
                     border-bottom-color: transparent; }
            .red{ background: red;
                 position:relative;}
             .th_date{
                    padding-top:0px; 
                    padding-bottom: 0px;
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
                    height: 80px!important;
                    width: 50px!important;}
             .span_date{
                   margin: 0px;
                   color:#6ab3e4;
                   font-size:12px;
          }
          .catalog_table{
    overflow: hidden;

    margin: 0;
    border:1px solid #8c8c8c;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tr_main{background-color:#f2f2f2;
         padding-top:3px;
         padding-bottom:3px;
}
.td_main{text-align:center;
         color:#262626;
         padding-top:3px;
         padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.th_main{
    color:#6ab3e4;
    padding-left:3%;
    width: 150px;
    font-size:16px;
}

.tr_second{
    background-color:#6ab3e4;
}
.th_second span{
    color:#8b8d8e;
}


          </style>
```

**Table**

```
 <table id="table" class="catalog_table" border="1" style="border:1px solid black;">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="tr_main">
                        <th class="th_main">Nume Prenume</th>

                        <th data-column="#column-0" id="column-0" class="th_date th_second hidden"><span class="span_date">25/10/16</span></th>

                        <th data-column="#column-1" id="column-1" class="th_date hidden"><span class="span_date">23/10/16</span></th>

                        <th data-column="#column-2" id="column-2" class="th_date th_second"><span class="span_date">25/10/16</span></th>

                        <th data-column="#column-3" id="column-3" class="th_date"><span class="span_date">25/10/16</span></th>

        <th data-column="#column-4" id="column-4" class="th_date th_second" ><span class="span_date">25/10/16</span></th>
<th data-column="#column-51" id="column-51" class="empty"></th>
 <th data-column="column-5" id="column-5" style="background: green; padding:0px; margin:0px;" class="th_date th_second"><span class="span_date">Total</span></th>                                     </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                                    <tr class="tr_main tr_second">
                        <td class="td_main">Bucurenco Alexandru</td>

                        <td class="td_main hidden" style="width:30px;">
                            <span>6</span>
                        </td>

                        <td class="td_main hidden" style="width:30px;">
                            <span></span>
                        </td>

                        <td class="td_main" style="width:30px;">
                            <span></span>
                        </td>

                        <td class="td_main" style="width:30px;">
                            <span></span>
                        </td>

                        <td class="td_main" style="width:30px;">
                            <span></span>
                        </td><td class="empty" style="width:30px;"></td>
                        <td class="td_main" style="width:30px;">
                            <span>6</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="tr_main">
                        <td class="td_main">A M</td>

                        <td class="td_main hidden" style="width:30px;">
                            <span></span>
                        </td>

                        <td class="td_main hidden" style="width:30px;">
                            <span>6</span>
                        </td>

                        <td class="td_main" style="width:30px;">
                            <span></span>
                        </td>

                        <td class="td_main" style="width:30px;">
                            <span></span>
                        </td>

                        <td class="td_main" style="width:30px;">
                            <span></span>
                        </td><td class="empty" style="width:30px;"></td>
                                                                        <td class="td_main" style="width:30px;">
                            <span>6</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="tr_main tr_second">
                        <td class="td_main">S S</td>

                        <td class="td_main hidden" style="width:30px;">
                            <span>9</span>
                        </td>

                        <td class="td_main hidden" style="width:30px;">
                            <span></span>
                        </td>

                        <td class="td_main" style="width:30px;">
                            <span></span>
                        </td>

                        <td class="td_main" style="width:30px;">
                            <span></span>
                        </td>

                        <td class="td_main" style="width:30px;">
                            <span>6</span>
                        </td><td class="empty" style="width:30px;"></td>
                                                                        <td class="td_main" style="width:30px;">
                            <span>7.5</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
            </table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.empty').on('mouseover',function(){
    $('.empty').toggleClass('red');
});
$('.empty').on('mouseout',function(){
    $('.empty').toggleClass('red');
});


});
```

Column that will be hovered is with class empty.
Th that going over is last id="column-5"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out https://jsfiddle.net/2x6uhow4/3/

```
.th_date{
    height: 80px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.th_date > div{
    transform:rotate(270deg);
    width: 30px;
}
```

the solution was to add a div inside your th and inside that div you add the span, after that rotate the div and you are good to go.

I've deleted some of the CSS attributes that is already inherited so there is no need to write them again and formatted the source code to be more readable.

TIP: try to reduce the number of classes used as you can, it's not a good thing to have a lot of classes where instead you can access those elements from their parents

Comment: Thanks, it's working . Classed are implemented by my js when i get table from controller